# Adding element to array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array that looks like the following:

[image]

I would like to add a new item, named "attributes", which is also an array. I can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using push?

Comment: Do you want to add to each object in the array?

Comment: This currently lacks information. What is the expected outcome after "adding an element"? Do you want to append an item, or simply assign some property to an array? Also, please don't just post images of code, write out the code instead.

Comment: After the "text" element. In the same level as "text", "key" and "enabled" I want one named "attributes"

Comment: That's simply `arr[0].attributes = myArray`. Use a for loop if you want to add attributes to each item.

Comment: I guess you don't want to add `attributes` just only to the first item of your array, do you?

Comment: @Patrick Yes I did, it says it's not a function. That array in the picture is in one variable named "oArray". oArray.push(oLine) gives me that error.

Comment: But you're mixing naming conventions. An "item" is a specific item of an array, `['hello', 'there']` is an array with two *items*. A *property* of an object is what you are after, and in order to create a property in an object you just assign it to something.

Comment: @EvaDias, no put the comment back. I was going to help you with it :)

Comment: @Patrick It's probable that I'm mixing naming conventions, yes. I'm a bit new in JS :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var test = [{
  enabled: true,
  key: 'FIN28',
  text: 'Service Agreement'
}, {
  enabled: true,
  key: 'test',
  text: 'test test'
}];

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  test[i]['attributes'] = [];
}
console.log(test);
```

Comment: @EvaDias, give me a more complete picture. Do you mean `attibutes` is an array of objects?

Comment: @EvaDias, oh so its an object of objects. one min :)

Comment: Thank you @AmmarCSE ! My problem was that the name "attributes" was  already in the variable to push into the oArray. I made a for and took the arrays inside to another variable, losing the "attributes:" part and it worked !

Comment: @EvaDias, ok but let me know if you need anymore help :)

Comment: Right now it looks perfect @AmmarCSE :) but thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you want to add an attribute named "attribute" to the object inside your array. you can do it like this :

```
myarray[0].attribute = myvalue;
```

If you want to do it for every item of your array, you can do this :

```
for(var idx in myarray)
    myarray[idx].attribute = myvalue;
```